# Observing changes on a single array element in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to observe changes on a single array element in Ember?

`[]` and `@each` properties can be used to observe changes on all array elements, but what if I am only interested in one element and don't want updates for the rest? Especially if the rest of the array is large and changing often.

I would have hoped that observing `things.[0].name` (or any other index within the array bounds) would work, am I missing something?

```
  atEachNameChanged: Ember.observer('things.@each.name', function() {
    this.get('messages').pushObject('@each triggered');
  }),

  atIndexedNameChanged: Ember.observer('things.[0].name', function() {
    this.get('messages').pushObject('[0] triggered');
  }),

  bracketNameChanged: Ember.observer('things.[].name', function() {
    this.get('messages').pushObject('[] triggered');
  }),
```

[Twiddle code sample](https://ember-twiddle.com/16d6e4325296b197709533f9828d277a?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 0):

Define alias computed property for `things.firstObject.name`.

```
firstObjName:Ember.computed.alias('things.firstObject.name'),
```

Observe `firstObjName`,

```
firstObjNameObserver:Ember.observer('firstObjName',function(){
    console.log('firstObjName observer');
  }),
```

Comment: This would only work for firstObject/lastObject, what about anything in between?